# Помогите получить участников рабочего процесса в SharePoint Workflow v.2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

Очень нужно получить список участников запущенного Workflow.
    Причем список участников из формы инициации. Т.е. **последний** отредактированный
    набор перед запуском процесса.

```
У меня есть ID элемента списка, для которого запущен этот рабочий процесс.
Что я делаю:

SPSite site = new SPSite("http://portal/projects");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPList list = web.Lists["Справочник проектов"];

SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(4613);
SPWorkflow wf = item.Workflows[0];

Console.WriteLine(wf.Xml);

Но проблема в том, что в Xml содержится информация об участниках кому не 
пришла ещё задача. Те кто уже выполнил задачу "выпадают" из Xml.
На просторах интернета я нашел, что нужно ковырять класс 
"SPWorkflowActivationProperties" свойство InitiationData, но как мне СВЯЗАТЬ 
экземпляр этого класса с моим запущенным Workflow чтобы получить из него 
информацию???
```